# Run multiple commands from cmd.exe in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have the following line that I want to execute from PowerShell:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential "doh\account" "`"cd c:\Projects `& dir`""
```

The problem is that the second command does not execute. I have looked at many articles and have tried multiple combinations of quotes and back ticks without success.

Comment: Why do you think you need to run `cd` and `dir` in CMD in the first place? PowerShell can do those things by itself. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: That is just an example. I need to be able to run more than one command.

Comment: I am trying to automate a deployment and need to execute several steps at the command prompt from my powershell script. The problem is I cannot get the second step to execute. The cd and dir are just two simple commands in my quest to get this to work.

Comment: Again, why is the Command Prompt a requirement? PowerShell can run external commands all by itself.

Comment: I am deploying a COTS product and the vendor directions require using the command prompt for the deployment. It is a JAVA app and uses Ant.

Comment: I'm not going to play Twenty Questions with you. Come back when you're willing to provide more detailed information about the actual task at hand. Have a nice day.

Comment: I am not playing twenty questions. I asked a very straightforward question. It really is a syntax issue. I don't understand why my question does not have enough information.  The manual process of deploying involves updating text in two xml files. Logging into the command prompt with the service account for the application. Going to the directory where the application resides and then issuing the ant command which updates the database. It is not a difficult process, just tedious when there are multiple servers to update.

Comment: The syntax issue is just a symptom of the underlying [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What you're asking simply isn't the way you do these things in PowerShell. What you actually want is something like this: `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Set-Location ...; & ant ...; ... } -Credential 'doh\account'`. However, it's hard to flesh out "something like" when you won't tell us what it is that you actually need to do.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
Start-Process cmd.exe -credential "doh\account" -ArgumentList "/K cd c:\projects & dir"
```

I ran "cmd /?" and it has the following argument available:
"/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains"

Still not sure why you want to do this though, if you want to elaborate on it we might able help more.